# Is there a way to rename.js files to .ts files using BABEL

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I want to rename my js files under src folder to ts files using Babel

I have run 
**babel src --out-dir lib -extensions \".js,.ts\" --source-maps inline"**

This converts ts files to js but not js files to ts.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you saying your babel output is typescript? Because usually your _input_ would be typescript, and your output would be javascript.

Comment: yes. I was able to rename the file to .ts using the command

babel src --out-dir lib -extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir-extension .ts

Comment: Cool, seems like you have your answer. I am curious though as to what the rest of your config is that allows you to do a conversion from `js` to `ts`. `js` is already valid `ts`, afaik, so what is getting converted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research I figured out that I can set the --out-file-extension to ts inorder convert from js to ts using BABEL.

babel src/ lib/ --out-file-extension .js

Comment: I tested your command and it doesn't work at all.